# Using username as salt safe enough?

Tags: hash, salt

Instead of creating a separate salt generator for each user, can't I just use their username as a salt? It would be unique for everyone, and achieves the purpose of the salts.

```
    <?php   
$hashedpass = sha1($username.$password)
 >?
```

If the username is too short to be used as a salt, I can just add a global string to the username.

```
$salt =$username.'asdf1234'
$hashedpass = sha1($salt.$password)
```

Would this be sufficient for security?
It still creates a unique salt for each user and prevents rainbow table attacks.

Comment: User names may be the same in a wide enough sample.

Comment: What happens if they change their username?

Comment: PHP has a [password_hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function that does everything the right way. Unless you have a very good reason not to, you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

User names are predictable. I would prefer using random value as a salt. An attacker could begin the generation of precumputed hash table targeting one user (admin?) even before obtaining the hash&salt to crack.

So, you should **NOT**.

**Edit**:

The main purpose of having a salt is that rainbow tables are useless. From my point of view, using a guessable value (even with static value added) as salt is bad practice as you allow an attacker to "prepare" the hashes before obtaining your database.

In some scenarios : if you distribute your code and you have a default "admin" account, an attacker will be able to reuse the rainbow table against all the installations of your software.

Other example from @Anti-weakpasswords : [Pyrit](https://code.google.com/p/pyrit/), "a WPA/WPA2 cracking tool, tool advantage of the WPA/WPA2 protocol using the SSID (username equivalent) as the salt to allow the precomputation of reasonably sized dictionaries against common SSID's - linksys, dlink, 2WIRE047."

Comment: What about mixing up, or adding a string to, the username?

Comment: You may want to explicitly state that you shouldn't use usernames as passwords. While I understand the risk of precomputation attacks, the OP might not get that from your answer.

Comment: @KunalChopra - what is the problem with using the built-in, well-tested functionality of PHP?

Comment: @r00t - an example you can add to your repertoire is that of [pyrit](https://code.google.com/p/pyrit/), a WPA/WPA2 cracking tool that took advantage of the WPA/WPA2 protocol using the SSID (username equivalent) as the salt to allow the precomputation of reasonably sized dictionaries against common SSID's - linksys, dlink, 2WIRE047, etc., just like an attacker could precompute an attack again common usernames like jsmith, joesmith, joes, joe.smith, etc.

Comment: @Anti-weakpasswords - Yes I added it to the answer. Thanks, that's a good "real-life" example.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the salt is guessable.  It only matters that it's computationally in-feasible to pre-compute the hashes, and that there's no commonly used set of salts.  You could randomly pick a 128 bit number as an initial sequence, and then just increment a counter each time you wanted to create a new salt.   That would be just as impossible to pre-compute as randomly generating each salt. The salt is guessable, but extremely unlikely that anyone else has started at the same 128 bit counter as you have.

Comment: I'd STILL recommend random generation, simply because it's easier, but this scenario is just as secure.  There may be some scenarios where generating a random number is difficult (embedded environments with no random source?).